# Explicitly defining fields on ModelSerializer overrides Django's Model parameters like verbose_name and validators

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Imagine having a simple model like the one bellow:

```py
from utils.validators import name_validator

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Customer Name", validators=[name_validator])
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Customer Email")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now if I explicitly define a filed on my `serializer`, both `validators` and `verbose_name` are lost. I can use `label=` and `validatos=` when defining the field on my `serializer` but I don't want to repeat myself. What if I have multiple serializer pointing to the same Model?

```py
class CustomerSerilizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_field_name = serializers.CharField(source="name")

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = "__all__"
```

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the perfect way of doing this or not, but I managed to achieve my desired behavior by writing a custom `ModelSerializer` which sets `label` and `validators` if they are not being passed when explicitly defining a field on the serializer.

```py
class CustomModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        model = self.Meta.model
        model_fields = [f.name for f in model._meta.get_fields()]

        for field_name, field_instance in self.fields.items():
            source_field = field_instance.source

            if source_field in model_fields:
                model_field = model._meta.get_field(source_field)

                if "label" not in field_instance._kwargs:
                    field_instance.label = model_field.verbose_name

                if "validators" not in field_instance._kwargs:
                    field_instance.validators.extend(model_field.validators)
```